# How to change the location of map and satellite buttons in Google Maps JS API?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I want to move the **satellite-map** buttons on the upper left corner of this simple example google maps code to the upper right corner, but I can not figure out how to do it.

Could you help me?

**Html**

```
<h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**js**

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

**css** (not necessary)

```
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want "mapTypeControlOptions" and set the "position"

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
    },
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    }
 });
}
```

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Comment: @SelinElibol, You're welcome, please accept the answer if it works for you.